# Explain different sensor on psensor

Tags: hardware, cpu, gpu, temperature, psensor

What sensor here shows the GPU temperature? I figured `Tctl` and `Tccd1` is CPU, but I could not find online what the other sensors are for. I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain them in human terms.

[image]

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu?

Comment: *psensor* is a package in the universe repos, this question doesn't seem that off base

Comment: You can guess certain sensors the sensor's preferences (right click > Preferences) by looking at the `Id` field.But, unfortunately, not all, which is why I landed on this unanswered question. -__-